# Theories of meta-interpretation?

Tags: hermeneutics

Is there any discussion in perhaps hermeneutical theory about meta-interpretation, which is when you try to interpret or understand something, by thinking about blindspots you have from your own perspective, which cause you to understand someone else from your perspective, rather than considering very unknown or unexpected contextual factors in their frame?

In other words, when you interpret something, you try to find out how it interprets itself, sort of. And that can go to higher levels of abstraction or self-reference, I think.